# Script not opening in terminal via desktop launcher

Tags: applications, pantheon-terminal, desktop, slingshot

Here's my **.desktop** file content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=wifite
Comment=WiFite , fight for WiFi
Exec=pantheon-terminal -e 'wifite --help' 
Icon=wifite
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;Application;Development;
StartupNotify=false
```

I even used this `Exec=gksudo pantheon-terminal -e '/usr/bin/x11/wifite.py'`.
But nothing works

Comment: I have added an answer.Mark it as answer if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the **Exec** line in the file to

```
pkexec pantheon-terminal -e "bash -c 'wifite;$SHELL'"
```

or (alternate version)

```
pantheon-terminal -e "bash -c 'pkexec wifite;$SHELL'"
```

Then try the **.desktop** file and see if it works :)

NOTE : I changed **gksudo** to **pkexec** so that you have a better looking password prompt.

Comment: Using pkexec it gives this "error accessing /usr/bin/x11/wifite.py :  no such file or directory

Comment: And using gksu it gives this "gtk-message: failed to load mofule" pantheon-filrchooser-module" and some gtk warning 3619 unable to locate theme engine in module_path "pixmap"

Comment: I just changed this 'gksudo wifite;$shell' " and it runs with error like i mentioned in 2nd comment and than it runs wifite but at sametime quits itself

Comment: Dude this line works exec=pantheon-terminal -e "bash -c 'pkexec wifite;$shell'"   thankyousomuch

Comment: On my laptop `exec=pantheon-terminal -e "bash -c 'pkexec wifite;$shell'"` works.The previous one doesn't because you are pointing to a non-existant file

Answer (score 0):

easy fix is, Go to AppCenter. Install Xterm then it works if you have Terminal=true